# Unable to add Card view to my project

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to add card view but when I add the libary using this dependency:
`compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'` I get the following error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
>   Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(26.0.0-alpha1) from [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1] AndroidManifest.xml:27:9-38
>       is also present at [com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1] AndroidManifest.xml:24:9-31 value=(25.3.1).
>       Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:25:5-27:41 to override.

Comment: Can you add your build.gradle file content with the question?

Answer (score 2):

There is a conflicting support library in your `build.gradle`. From the error, you have a `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1` library which is in conflict with `com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1`. `cardview-v7` is already including the `appcompat-v7` in it. So, you need to use remove the `appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1` or using the same support library version.

You also need to check each dependency in your build.gradle. If you found the library is using support library internally, you can exclude it by using something like this:

```
compile('com.the.library:libraryname:1.0.0') { 
   exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7' 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are using different versions of the Android Support Libraries:

Use like following the same version

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
```